# Regex for parsing SQL parameters

Tags: sql, regex

If I have a query such as `SELECT * from authors where name = @name_param`, is there a regex to parse out the parameter names (specifically the "name_param")?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. Can you clarify, or give an example? Do you want to pass in a list of names and have it convert the WHERE to name in (name_a, name_b, ...) ? and you need to specify the RDBMS, Regex support is different between them.

Answer (score 9):

This is tricky because params can also occur inside quoted strings.

```
SELECT * FROM authors WHERE name = @name_param 
  AND string = 'don\'t use @name_param';
```

How would the regular expression know to use the first `@name_param` but not the second?

It's a problem that can be solved, but it's not practical to do it in a single regular expression.  I had to handle this in Zend_Db, and what I did was first strip out all quoted strings and delimited identifiers, and then you can use regular expressions on the remainder.

You can see the code, because it's open-source.
See functions `_stripQuoted()` and `_parseParameters()`.

https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/136735e776f520b081cd374012852cb88cef9a88/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php#L200
https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/136735e776f520b081cd374012852cb88cef9a88/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php#L140

Comment: Not to mention parameter names appearing in SQL comments.  Regexes are great, but not necessarily great for parsing jobs.

Comment: Too bad link wasn't working. I was also looking for a way to exclude quoted string and comments.

Comment: @Shinjo I have updated the link to the current location of the code I described.

Answer (score 4):

Given you have no quoted strings or comments with parameters in them, the required regex would be quite trivial:

```
@([_a-zA-Z]+)       /* match group 1 contains the name only */
```

I go with [Bill Karwin's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307929/regex-for-parsing-sql-parameters#307957) to be cautious, knowing that the naïve approach has its pitfalls. But if you kow the data you deal with, this regex would be all you need.

Comment: Small remark : numbers are also valid in parameter names so the regex should be @([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)

Comment: @gissolved it's true, but I think parameter can't start with digits, and maybe not even with an underscore. So I'd use `@([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)`.