# How can I determine the parameters required by an arbitrary piece of T-SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, reflection

Basically, I'm looking for an equivalent to `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` that will work for arbitrary T-SQL.

For example, this query requires one parameter:

```
SELECT @Foo [Foo], '@Bar' [Bar], @Baz [Baz]
```

I basically need to extract:

```
new[] { "Foo", "Baz" }
```

From above.  I could build a SQL parser, but I have an open connection to SQL server, so I'd prefer to use an existing option if possible.

---

**Edit:**

There *has* to be a way to do this, because SQL Server's Business Intelligence Development Studio is able to do this very successfully.

---

**Edit 2:**

SQL BIDS is executing this command in order to describe the results:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET FMTONLY ON;SELECT @Foo [Foo], ''@Bar'' [Bar], @Baz [Baz]',
    N'@Foo sql_variant,@Baz sql_variant',
    @Foo=NULL,@Baz=NULL
```

Which explains how it can determine the columns, but it *may* be just string parsing to get the parameters...

Comment: How are you building up this initial string? Is there something you can use that you're using to dynamically build up this string to find the required parameters?

Comment: Does SQL Profiler show anything interesting if you watch the server while getting Business Intelligence Development Studio to do this? Would tell us if it's a server function or just string parsing

Comment: Perhaps just use a regular expression to find the @variables that aren't enclosed within quotes... that should work I think.

Comment: Are you aware of [Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx)?

Comment: @Martin; OMG! I think that is what I need.  Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @Martin: Post this code:

`            var sql = "SELECT @Foo [Foo], '@Bar' [Bar], @Baz [Baz]";
            var p = new TSql100Parser(true);
            var errors = new List<ParseError>();
            var tokens = p.GetTokenStream(new StringReader(sql), errors);
            if (errors.Count == 0)
            {
                var variables = (from t in tokens
                                 where t.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Variable
                                 select t.Text).ToArray();
            }`

Comment: @John - Thanks. That's much more concise than what I was trying!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx) for this. I'm not familiar with it myself but I just tried parsing your statement and could see that the variables were accessible in the `ScriptTokenStream` collection (not sure if there is an easier way of getting hold of them or not)

Edit: Posting the OP's own code from the comments!

```
    var sql = "SELECT @Foo [Foo], '@Bar' [Bar], @Baz [Baz]";
    var p = new TSql100Parser(true);
    var errors = new List<ParseError>();
    var tokens = p.GetTokenStream(new StringReader(sql), errors);
    if (errors.Count == 0)
    {
        var variables = (from t in tokens where t.TokenType == 
                       TSqlTokenType.Variable select t.Text).ToArray();
    }
```

SQL Server 2012 also introduces [`sp_describe_undeclared_parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878260.aspx) which is of relevance but fails with this example as it needs to be able to deduce datatypes.

Comment: How can I use this to get the tables in a SQL query. I tried replacing Variable with Table in your code. It's not working. When I use Identifier it gives both column names and table names. Is there a way to get only table names?

Comment: @DeepanCool Gert Draper's answer here looks like it will do that https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/24fd8fa5-b1af-44e0-89a2-a278bbf11ae0/parsing?forum=ssdt

Answer (score 2):

Use RegEx and parse the parameters, I quickly tested this, so not sure if will work, might need modiciation.

[^']@([^[,]+)

If you need to modify the regular expression string, I find this site very helpful: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string query = "SELECT @Foo [Foo], '@Bar' [Bar], @Baz [Baz] ";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"[^']@([^\[,]+)");
        MatchCollection collection = r.Matches(query);
        string[] array = new string[collection.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            array[i] = collection[i].Value.Trim();

            // If you want the string[] populated without the "@"
            // array[i] = collection[i].Groups[1].Value.Trim();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` works by asking SQL Server what the parameters are, which is not an option in this case. Some sort of string processing like a RegEx is probably your best bet.

This Regex might be able to do it

```
@([_a-zA-Z]+)
```

Haven't tried it myself, but its from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307929/regex-for-parsing-sql-parameters/308162#308162)

It will also find parameters in comments and quoted strings but its a start.