# C# - SQL WITH clause

Tags: c#, sql, common-table-expression

Just fishing for ideas-

I have a SQL statement that I need to parse in C#. It is formatted basically as follows -

```
    WITH TableX as (

    -- something else could be here..
    select field1, field2, .. fieldX
    from mytable
    -- something else could be here..

    )

    -- something else could be here..
    select /*THESE FIELDS ARE BEING REPLACED*/ TableX.field1, TableX.field2, .. TableX.fieldX
    from TableX
    -- something else could be here.. ie, more joins, selecting from subqueries. Basically another select could exist here.
```

Any ideas on how to replace "TableX.field1, TableX.field2, .. TableX.fieldX" with another group of field guaranteed to be in the result set?

Comment: I don't think your example is very clear yet. Could the "something else"s literally be anything (such as a complete query, followed by another `WITH`)? Do we/you have to specifically pick out the `TableX` defintion from multiple CTEs, and if so, what feature picks them out. Take a step back, and try to read your question without any knowledge of the specific problem. Which facts are absent, or would make you have to guess?

Comment: Is this about string replacement, or about how CTEs work?

Comment: This is about string replacement. And the "-- something else could be here" should be pretty obvious.

Comment: With a "WITH" statement in SQL, the WITH defines a temporary result set that can be selected from. What I am looking for is those fields that are selected from that result set and replacing them.

Comment: Search for the line containing '/*THESE FIELDS ARE BEING REPLACED*/' then perform your replacements. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a complete sql parser to build a parse tree, then replace the items selectively from there.

non-trivial task.

Comment: Do you think it would work to look for the first select after the closing parentheses of the definition of TableX?

Comment: [You don't need to roll your own parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792507/how-can-i-determine-the-parameters-required-by-an-arbitrary-piece-of-t-sql/5793088#5793088)