# How can I determine the number of expected parameters in an arbitrary SQL statement?

Tags: .net, sql, smo

I want to author some .NET code (preferably C#) that determines the number of expected parameters in an arbitrary SQL statement. For example, this statement

```
EXEC etlp.LogPackageEnd ?,?,?
```

expects 3 parameters.

As a SQL novice, I spent time reading other posts on how to solve this problem. I've already tried using the TSql100Parser.GetTokenStream, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792507/how-can-i-determine-the-parameters-required-by-an-arbitrary-piece-of-t-sql), but it returned parse errors for each question mark. I also tried using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser.Parser.Parse() but got an error of Incorrect syntax near ?

I realize I could use a regex but I'm looking for a generic solution; my understanding is that the parameter format can change so question marks aren't the indicators.

Comment: Are you trying to find the number of arguments to a stored procedure?

Comment: Not just stored procedures. I believe question marks can be used as placeholders for parameters in OLE-DB SQL statements. Additionally, question marks may appear in a statement like SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = ? I'd like to be handle these types of statements, as well as when executing a stored procedure.

Comment: the OleDbCommandBuilder provides a DeriveParameters method when the command type is a StoredProcedure, but MSDN docs specifically state you can't use that method against a parameterized query :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.parameters
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourProcedureName')
```