# Regex Lookahead and Lookbehind to parse SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, regex

I am trying to parse SQL statements with regex and save it's parameters to use later.

Lets say I have this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, name, email) VALUES (@id, @name, @email)
```

The following regex will work just fine:

```
(@[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+)
```

However in this statement I should ignore everything in ' ' or " " and save only first parameter:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET id = @id, name = 'myname@id' WHERE id = 1;
```

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/307957 "it's not practical to do it in a single regular expression", but I am still trying to do this.

I tried to add Regex Lookahead and Lookbehind, but its not working:

```
(?<!\').*(@[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+).*(?!\')
```

Is there any way to do it using only one regular expression? Should I use lookahead/lookbehind or something else?

Comment: maybe this could help. https://regex101.com/r/gI7cL6/3

Comment: Regex isn't the way to go. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java

Comment: @wu4m4n thank you for the tip

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yea, thats true. But for educational purposes why not use regex?)

Comment: For educational purposes, find an other example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your regex. Note the group you want always to capture is followed with `,` or `)`. Being aware of this fact you get this regex:

```
(@[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+)(?=[,)])
```

- `@[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+` is your value
- `(?=[,)])` checks if the `)` or `,` character follows.

If the way describing where your string can't be placed is complicated, better look where it must be places instead.

See how it works at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nW7lZ9/1).

Comment: Yea, if string has ) or , like name = 'myname@id,something' then it will pass the regex

Comment: According your input, it works. If you want the solution with a wider coverage, please provide more sample inputs.

Comment: I think it's enough. You mentioned Lookahead, so I mark the question as answered, thank you!

If you want to look for another example: https://regex101.com/r/nW7lZ9/3

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `[\=\(\s]\s*\@[0-9+^a-zA-Z_0-9$_]+\s*[\),]`

**Explanation**:

`[\=\(\s]` match a single character present in the list below

- `\=` matches the character = literally
- `\(` matches the character ( literally
- `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

`\s*` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

- Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `\@` matches the character `@` literally
  `[0-9+^a-zA-Z_0-9$_]+` match a single character present in the list below
- Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- `+^` a single character in the list `+^` literally
- `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
- `A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case insensitive)
- `_` the literal character `_`
- `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- `$_` a single character in the list `$_` literally

`\s*` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

- Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`[\),]` match a single character present in the list below

- `\)` matches the character `)` literally
- `,` the literal character `,`

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, thank you very much, I will use it too.